# Regex required to identify an exact pattern with slashes

Tags: regex

I need to use regex to find exact matches of Transaction Codes from a source string.

[Example 1]

(Source String Given in the below line)

Please provide access to execute the Tcodes: FBL1N, FBL5N, ME23N

(I need to find the below Tcodes in the above Source String)

ME23N (Should be found)

ME23 (Should not be found)

FBL5N (Should be found)

FBL5 (Should not be found)

[End of example 1]

In the above example, I am trying to find the tcode by enclosing it within word boundaries (\b)

So if I need to find ME23N, my regex will be \bME23N\b
This is fetching me the correct matches

But I am facing an issue with the below scenario

[Example 2]

(Source String Given below)

Please provide access to execute the below custom Tcodes:

/MRP1/DD5, /GBP/PO1, /ROR23/TRP2/HH34, /IJK67/UYT/ORE

(I need to find the below Tcodes in the above Source String)

/ROR23/TRP2/HH34 (Should be found)

/ROR23/TRP2 (Should not be found)

[End of example 2]

In the above example, if I use the regex - \b\/ROR23\/TRP2\/HH34\b, this does not work and does not find a match. (Not sure why as I'm not good with regex)

If I search directly for the string \/ROR23\/TRP2\/HH34, it works

But if I search /ROR23/TRP2 then this also matches which I don't want/need as I just need an exact match

Any help would be appreciated on what sort of regex search should I do. Thanks!

Comment: The first word boundary in `\b\/ROR23\/TRP2\/HH34\b` makes the pattern match only after a letter, digit or `_`, i.e. at the word boundary. You probably just need `\/ROR23\/TRP2\/HH34\b`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Could you please tell me what to use so that I get only exact matches

Comment: `\/ROR23\/TRP2\/HH34\b`???

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - \/ROR23\/TRP2\/HH34\b works but even \/ROR23\/TRP2\b is giving me a match which I don't want.
I want an exact match - So that when I search for the code /ROR23/TRP2 - It should not give me a match.

Comment: There are a lot of meanings of "exact match". What do you mean? Between spaces? `(?<!\S)\/ROR23\/TRP2\/HH34(?!\S)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no word boundary between a space and `/` that is why `\b\/ROR23\/TRP2\/HH34\b` does not match.

For the examples in the quesion, you can assert a whitespace boundary to the left if a lookbehind is supported, and add a word boundary to the right, asserting not followed by `/` as you seems to have strings with slashes and can be followed by a comma.

Note that if the delimiters of the pattern are not `/` then you don't have to escape the `/`.

For example:

```
(?<!\S)\/ROR23\/TRP2\/HH34\b(?!\/)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DxSm0a/1).

Another option is to assert the allowed chars to the right, being for example a whitespace char, comma or the end of the string.

```
(?<!\S)\/ROR23\/TRP2\/HH34(?=[\s,]|$)
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x2uet8/1).